# Android braintree paypal not working with dexguard integration

Tags: android, paypal, braintree, dexguard

We have integrated Braintree Dropin, We have an issue with Braintree dropin UI SDK in Android, I'm using dexGuard in release build, when We build app without dexGuard app will work fine and It displays payPal & credit card option in dropin UI, But when We use dexGuard then in dropin there is only Credit Card option, paypal is not displaying, Also as per Braintree proguard rules are already applied in SDK, so "no "need to configure manually.

[Integrated Brain tree](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/client-sdk/setup/android/v2)

We have integrated below code:

```
DropInRequest dropInRequest = new DropInRequest().clientToken(aClientokenResponce.getClientToken()); .
startActivityForResult(dropInRequest.getIntent(getContext()), REQUEST_CODE_BRAINTREE);
```

I've used following in my Gradle file:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFile getDefaultDexGuardFile('dexguard-release.pro')
        proguardFile 'dexguard-project.txt'
    }
    debug {
    }
}
```